# BeautifulSoup4 documentation example doesn't work

Tags: python, function, beautifulsoup

I am newbie in BeautifulSoup4 and learning it very intensively. The problem is with the next piece of code(I found it in documentation on the page **https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/**, article about function definition):

```
  def has_class_but_no_id(tag):
    return tag.has_attr('class') and not tag.has_attr('id')     (A)
  soup.find_all(has_class_but_no_id)
```

I expected to get result like this(seen in the documentation):

```
  # [<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>,
  #  <p class="story">Once upon a time there were...</p>,       (B)
  #  <p class="story">...</p>]
```

But I got the next result:

```
  [<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>, <p class="story">Once 
  upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were
  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>,                     
  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">Lacie</a> and
  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tillie</a>; 
  and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p>, <p class="story">...</p>]
```

I checked documentatation and found only the method **.has_attr** is deprecated. And no any more details. How can I change initial code (A) to get expected result (B)? Can anybody help to fix this problem? Thnx.

Comment: "I expected to get result like this" - but the actual output is?..

Comment: (there is a deprecation warning for `has_key` in the code, but not sure about `has_attr` : *'has_key is deprecated. Use has_attr("") instead.*)

Comment: Execuse me! It was my fault. I fixed it in my request. I changed code and link to documentation site. Check my question again, please...

Comment: **I renamed one method for compatibility with Python 3: 
     Tag.has_key() -> Tag.has_attr()**  -   You can check it  on above mentioned documentation page....

Answer (score 1):

It works.
You must notice, the second result in the list was not checked for the same conditions in the tags inside (child tags). So the wrapping `<p class="story">` have met conditions and has been placed in result list with all it's content.

This result list:

```
[<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>,
 -------------------------
 <p class="story">Once 
      upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were
      <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
      <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">Lacie</a> and
      <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tillie</a>; 
      and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p>,
 -------------------------
 <p class="story">...</p>]
```

contains three tags, every item has 'class' attr and no 'id' attr.

Comment: Thnx. But for me is important: how to change initial piece of code (A) to get expected result (B)

Comment: Is it trolling?
You don't have to change anything.

Comment: No. I just misunderstood your coment. Everything is ok.Deeply apologize...

Answer (score 0):

Doc says:

> This function only picks up the **'p'** tags.It doesn’t pick up the **'a'** tags, because those tags define both “class” and “id”. It doesn’t pick up tags like 'html' and 'title', because those tags don’t define “class”.

```
 soup.find_all(has_class_but_no_id)
# [<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>,
#  <p class="story">Once upon a time there were...</p>,
#  <p class="story">...</p>]
```

It is unclear and it leads people to expect a result without any a tag.They should change the statement or example.